# How to fix this problem? (Express Next())

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a code snippet as below:

```
app.get('/admin', checkAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
 if(req.user.info.role == 'admin') {
   return res.render('admin', { nama: req.user.nama })
 } else {
   return next(createError(403)) 
 }
})
```

I login as admin, and what happens is, node.js does not render the page, instead runs

> next(createError(403)).

How to fix this problem?

Comment: can you console.log req.user.info.role and find out if it is admin or not

Comment: Yes, the results are admin

Comment: So you're saying `req.user.info.role == 'admin'` evaluates to `true` but the `else` statement is executing?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: And you are sure the `checkAuthenticated` middleware can't possibly be responsible for executing `next(createError(403))`? Perhaps, it also has some sort of logic that can result in such execution.